# Excel: recode values in a row that come before a text value, but not after

Tags: excel, replace

I have a series of values in a row: numbers and letters; 0,2 or B in each cell. I'd like to replace the number 2 with a letter, depending on whether the 2 comes before or after the letter B. 
I.e. recode this 00202B00BBB2BB20 to this 00P0PB00BBBUBBU0
Any suggestions very much appreciated.

Comment: Is this the same question as [this one][1].If so, see the referenced workbook.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17030956/excel-recode-all-non-zero-values-in-a-row-based-on-position-relative-to-a-text

Answer (score 3):

Your rule doesn't seem very consistent (how does the "P" in position 3 appear, versus the "P" in position 5), but this should be a start; enter your text in A1, then in B1:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"2B","PB"),"B2","BU")
```

You can nest a third substitute to clear out the remainder of the 2s that are neither before nor after, or modify them to match your rule however you intend.

Based on comments, the actual rule is different.  Instead, use something like this:

```
B1: =FIND("B",A1)
C1: =SUBSTITUTE(left(a1,b1),"2","P") & SUBSTITUTE(mid(a1,b1, len(a1)+1),"2","U")
```

Comment: @Joe - sorry for the lack of clarity, been a long day! My case is more complex than I described. I have multiple rows,

Comment: @Joe - neat solution. Sorry for the lack of clarity, been a long day! My case is more complex than I described, be grateful for your advice. Replacement of the 2's depends on whether they come before or after the first occurrence of a B, rather than whether the 2 is right next to a B. So the first B divides how the 2s are recoded. So from 00202B020BBB2BB20 to 00P0PB0U0BBBUBBU0